# How to hide a column with Kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

I use a tmuxinator to generate a tmux window that watchs the output of some kubectl commands like:

```
watch -n 5 kubectl get pods/rc/svc/pv/pvc
```

But sometimes the output of Kubectl get too wide, i.e the selector column after rolling updates, and I would like not to show it on my setup. How do I do this with kubectl alone?

awk or cut can do the job too, but I could not figure out a way of doing this without loosing the table formating.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no explicit support for selecting a subset of columns in kubectl, but there are a few ways to accomplish this. You already mentioned `awk` which can be pared with `column -t` to get a nice table format:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | awk {'print $1" " $2'} | column -t
NAMESPACE    NAME
kube-system  fluentd-cloud-logging-k8s-stclair-minion-wnzd
kube-system  kube-dns-v10-fo6gl
kube-system  kube-proxy-k8s-stclair-minion-wnzd
...
```

Alternatively, you could use the go-template output of kubectl to create a custom output (which you could also pair with column), e.g. to print pod names and the first 8 characters of the UID:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=go-template='{{println "NAME UID"}}{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}} {{printf "%.8s\n" .metadata.uid}}{{end}}' | column -t
NAME                                           UID
fluentd-cloud-logging-k8s-stclair-minion-wnzd  8bcb7129
kube-dns-v10-fo6gl                             90bce35e
kube-proxy-k8s-stclair-minion-wnzd             8bc752c8
kubernetes-dashboard-v0.1.0-cptxn              90d18852
l7-lb-controller-v0.5.2-n6i23                  90daf833
```

More on go-templates [here](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/). A variant of [JSONpath](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath/) is also supported.

Answer (score 37):

Rather than using a second tool/binary like awk and column. you can use the flag `-o=custom-columns` in this way:
`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,Namespace:.metadata.namespace`

This is also an alternative and easy way to output custom columns than go-templates or jsonpath!

Comment: Here's another useful example of custom-columns: Show cluster-ip and ports of a service: `kubectl get svc my-service -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP,PORT:.spec.ports[*].targetPort`

Comment: For me, the above example will only be useful when I have one more column added to it which states the type(ClusterIP or NodePort)!

Comment: This is a better answer! Thx @NoamManos for the additional example to show the array data type. On Zshell, I notice we should surround the query expr in single quote to avoid a shell syntax error: `kubectl get svc my-service -o=custom-columns='NAME:.metadata.name,IP:.spec.clusterIP,PORT:.spec.ports[*].targetPort'`

Comment: Get with `-o yaml` first and that will show you the spec. Then from that you can pick custom columns for any get you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Kubectl command to get pods only by pod names or NAME column

```
kubetcl get pods -o NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON path to get only the desired output.

```
$ kubectl get nodes  -o='jsonpath'="{range .items[*].metadata }{.name}{'\n'}{end}"
```

kind-k8s-playground-control-plane
kind-k8s-playground-worker
kind-k8s-playground-worker2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).