# K8s - CRD - Remove a column

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am creating CRD in K8s cluster.
I am able to print all the details as shown here.

`kubectl get resource-kind`

My only issue is - I would like to remove 1 column which gets printed. Is there anyway to remove a column like 'Age' from printing?

**Note:**

I had explored `priority` option of `additionalPrinterColumns` which does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try use awk
kubectl get resource-kind | awk '{$number of your column=""; print $0}'

Comment: Hi , my question was - how to make it part of the CRD itself!!

Comment: Maybe that would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/53819162/16789286

Comment: :(, just to be clear, `kubectl get resource-kind` - this is what I want to do. I do not want to add anything else. internally I would like to remove columns for this kind. hope it is clear,